# Share android app apk

Tags: android, apk

I want my android application to have an option to share its apk file via email on a button click.I know how to use URI and mail intent, the problem is finding apk file.

What is the best way to access the apk and share it by email intent?

Comment: Use Google and find out how to attach a binary file to an email.

Comment: the problem is not how to attach, it is how to access .apk file of app

Comment: Just put it into some folder?

Comment: can't get the file from the main package of app where it has installed?

Comment: Are you aware that you can't redistribute other apps, because it's **illegal**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please use below function to send email with attachment

```
public static void attachFileviaEmail(Context p_context,String p_subject,String p_filePath)
{
    Uri m_uri;
    File m_file = new File(p_filePath);
    String m_emailTo = "Receiver Email ID";
    if(m_file.exists())
    {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{m_emailTo});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, p_subject);

        m_uri = Uri.parse("file://" + p_filePath);
        if(m_uri != null)
        {
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, m_uri);
        }
        //  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi pl find attachment.....");
        p_context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, p_context.getString(R.string.lbl_send_email)));
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is not how to attach, it is how to access .apk file of app

Comment: access means start apk ?

Comment: no, I want to share an apk file, so where is the apk of app? in which folder? does it exist or I should put it in app manually?

Comment: yes you should have to copy apk file in SDcard or download apk file in SDCard .and then refer that apk file path

Comment: can't get the file from the main package of app where it has installed?

Comment: how to copy apk file from project to sd card?

Comment: you have any specific url of apk file ? may be you are confuse .